# How to bring back the old material EditText component?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I want to use the old EditText material component in android. Currently, I'm using the latest Material Component Libary because there is a lot of views using it.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

But, I want to use the old EditText one.

I've tried to set the boxBackgroundMode to none, I get what I want. But there is a little margin to the left of the hint.

This is the code I use.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilLoginEmail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xl"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_xl"
    android:hint="@string/label_email"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvLoginWelcome"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvLoginWelcome">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1AeS.jpg

The result, there is a little margin to the left of the hint, I want the margin to disappear. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you show me, what kind of view you actually want?

Comment: I want to make view like this https://i.imgur.com/8mAhkHU.png

Comment: Hi, @GoLok please check my answer. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you use support library version 28.0.0 you will get the same material feel without using this library.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Then add this code in your XML file:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/tilUsername"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/username">

         <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/tetUsername"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:inputType="text"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In future, if you want to use any `FilledBox` or `OutlinedBox` for `TextInputLayout` you will be able to do that just bu adding one `style`.

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

In that case, your `TextInputLayout` will be like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/tilUsername"
          style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/username">
```

Comment: May i ask another question? Let's say i have a Material Button and i want to add a drawable to that it. So i use app:icon="@drawable/google", that's work great too but the icon displayed is tinted on my colorPrimary even though the google drawable is so colorful.. is there workaround about it? Thanks

Comment: Didn't get you properly. Like If your button only contains icon, can't you use image button for that?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Km067g1.png I create this one using LinearLayout, and this one using MaterialButton https://i.imgur.com/ZuANiht.png .The one i created using MaterialButton made the google logo tinted by blue .. I want it to be like my button i created using LinearLayout can i do it?

Comment: @GoLok, Try to use app:iconTint="@null" as property in your MaterialButton.

Comment: wow thank you so much, i don't have many reputation to upvote for your answer. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 3):

You can set the style of the TextInputLayout to style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout".

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```